# Как сделать такой select запрос?

Tags: mysql

Есть 3 таблицы:

recipe - `id, name`
ингредиенты - `id, name`
таблица связей - `recipe_ingredient (recipe_id, ingredient_id)`

Как мне сделать выборку из данных таблиц, если мне нужно искать рецепт, максимально похожий к выбранным пользователем ингредиентам?

Comment: Покажите пример таблицы и желаемый результат. Какие данные в 3-й таблице? для одного рецепта может быть несколько ингредиентов?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сначала следует определиться, что вы подразумеваете под «максимально похожий к выбранным пользователем ингредиентам». Например:

1. В рецепте присутствует максимальное число ингредиентов выбранных пользователем.
2. В рецепте нет ингредиентов не выбранных пользователем, при этом в рецепте  максимум выбранных ингредиентов.

Пример запроса:

```
SELECT
    recipe_id,
    COUNT(CASE
            WHEN ingredient_id IN (1,2,3) -- Перечень имеющихся ингредиентов через запятую
                THEN NULL
            ELSE 1
          END) AS ing_notfound_count,  
    COUNT(CASE
            WHEN ingredient_id IN (1,2,3) -- Перечень имеющихся ингредиентов через запятую
                THEN 1
          END) AS ing_found_count               
FROM recipe_ingredient
GROUP BY recipe_id
ORDER BY ing_notfound_count ASC, ing_found_count DESC;
```

Запрос вернет столбцы рецепт, число ингредиентов не указанных пользователем в нем и число указанных ингредиентов в нем.